# save password input as sha1() into db with symfony

Tags: forms, symfony1, save, sha1

I'm wracking my brain on the most simple of things.

I have a symfony-generated form with some customisation. I have the form saving just fine, except that the 'password' field writes the password (as expected) in normal format.

How can I intercept this value before database-entry and sha1() it before writing?

Code is essentially:

```
$this->dialog = $request->getParameter('dialog');
$this->form = new UserForm();

if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('user'));
    // intercept here, I suspect
    $user = $this->form->save();
}
```

EDIT:
Problem solved.

in */lib/model/User.php*

> class User extends BaseUser {
>
> ```
> public function save(PropelPDO $con = null)
> {
>
>   if ($this->getPassword() != '')
>   {
>     $this->setPassword(sha1($this->getPassword()));
>   }
>
>   return parent::save($con);
> }
> ```
>
> }

It's fairly obvious, but not for a noob like myself. hopefully this helps someone else. If there's a better way to do this without having to extend the save() function, let me know?

Resource: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/10 (See: *Protecting the Job Form with a Token*)

EDIT #2: Better way to do this (as per Grad's suggestion below)

In User model

```
public function setPassword($rawPassword) 
{ 
    $salt = "fgv932g2e9dshdfkdjgf927gf8hlz082";
    $password = sha1($salt . $rawPassword); 
    parent::setPassword($password);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 'better' do override the `setPassword()` function on your `User` Model.

something like this:

```
public function setPassword($rawPassword, $algo = 'sha1', $salt = null) {
  if ($salt === null) {
     $salt = sha1(time().rand().$this->id.$this->username);
  }
  $password = hash($algo, $rawPassword.$salt);
  $this->_set('password', $password);
  $this->_set('password_algo', $algo);
  $this->_set('password_salt', $salt);
}
```

This way you can set the password from everywhere (your current solution only works for new users).

(And, on a side note: don't forget to salt your password. :-) )

Comment: Hi Grad! Thank you for that. So obvious! However, I've updated your function slightly, seems to be a better idea (and yes, the function is very salty!) ;) ... see original post!

Comment: You can make it even saltier ;-) if you also save the salt to the database, and make it dynamic per user. (see my updated code)

Comment: lol! too much salt is bad for your health, you know ... hehe! :)